# Visual Studio is crashing without error message

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I have MS Visual Studio Enterprise 2015. It's regularly crashes without any error message, then restarts by itself on start page.

Nearly in 5% percents of all cases it offers me to recovery project, but then shows me that it can't open .vcxproj(helps only manual restarting project or studio). There isn't any time dependencies: it can crash after 30 seconds from start and can after 2 hours. Also crash happens everywhere: while writing code, in opened debugger or while compiling. This situation repeats in all projects.

I used repair in installator and deleted/install studio nearly 10 times with different installators, but crashing is continue.

I will be grateful if you can help me with advice or some links with similar problem decision.

Event Viewer message:

```
Faulting application name: devenv.exe, version: 14.0.25420.1, time stamp: 0x57685d85

Faulting module name: MSWB7.dll, version: 6.3.9600.17415, time stamp: 0x54504873

Exception code: 0xc0000005

Fault offset: 0x0001b947

Faulting process id: 0x1088

Faulting application start time: 0x01d2826f82c895a8

Faulting application path: C:\1\VS2015\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\MSWB7.dll

Report Id: 020e48c1-eec3-11e6-830a-645a047df224

Faulting package full name: 

Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Other messages are same: time stamp, exception code, fault offset and faulting module path.

Comment: Check event viewer.  See what errors show up.  Otherwise, not enough information to go on.

Comment: Where can I find it?

Comment: sounds like you need to contact microsoft for support.

Comment: MSWB7.dll = wordbreaker dll from windows. do you use an extension what provides spell checking? If yes, remove this extension.